# Pass piped value to child component

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-pipe

I used to have this code:

```
<icon imgSrc="/dist/resources/images/price-tag.png" class="icon pull-xs-left"></icon>
<div id="price-value" class="value">
   {{result?.averagePrice | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}
</div>
```

But i made it into a component so now to use it it is like:

```
<icon-with-value imgSrc="/dist/resources/images/price-tag.png" [value]='result?.averagePrice' class="icon pull-xs-left"></icon-with-value>
```

But i need to get the `result?.averagePrice` to display as currency. It was doing that before I made it a component as you can see. How do I convert this: `[value]='result?.averagePrice'` to pass it in with a currency pipe like this: `[value]='result?.averagePrice | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2''`

Comment: Use double quotes: `[value]="result?.averagePrice | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'"`

Comment: @JBNizet Thats works. Thanks!